# Exporting tables to text using Toad db2

Tags: toad

I would like to export a table data to text file from a SQL script using Toad db2. Currently, I can do it in excel and with .csv format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use db2, but I do use TOAD (for Oracle). If those versions aren't that different, here's how I do it.

1. right-click anywhere in data grid window; choose **Export dataset** option
2. format is "Delimited text"
3. default delimiter is comma; set it to something different, if you want
4. the result (opened in a text editor)

See if this helps.

[image]